# servicestack Razor view with request and response DTO

Tags: servicestack

I'm having a go with the razor functionality in service stack. 
I have a razor cshtml view working for one of my response DTO's.

I need to access some values from the request DTO in the razor view that have been filled in from some fields from the REST route, so i can construct a url to put into the response html page and also label some form labels.

Is there anyway of doing this?  I don't want to duplicate the property from the request DTO into the response DTO just for this html view.  Because i'm trying to emulate an existing REST service of another product, i do not want to emit extra data just for the html view.

eg
`http://localhost/rest/{Name}/details/{Id}`

eg

```
    @inherits ViewPage<DetailsResponse>
   @{

        ViewBag.Title = "todo title";
        Layout = "HtmlReport";
   }
```

this needs to come from the request dto NOT @Model

`<a href="/rest/@Model.Name">link to user</a>`
`<a href="/rest/@Model.Name/details/@Model.Id">link to user details</a>`

Comment: There's no way other than to add your DTO to the view model ... unless you want to add it to one of the auxiliary objects like the `ViewBag`, the `Page` object, the `Session`, etc.

Comment: i'm new to razor.   how would i add it to the ViewBag object?     Other way I just thought of, is if i detect it is not ?f=json or xml, i could return a wrapper htmlResponseDTO that contains request and response objects

Comment: Yes, I would go with your idea of a wrapper object that contains both -- ViewBag is not advisable, because isn't not strongly typed and therefore poses maintenance problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the `Request DTO` it needs to be referenced by either by adding the Request to the Response DTO (which you don't want to do), so the other option is to add it to the `IHttpRequest.Items` Dictionary which is the preferred way to pass data between your filters and services.

```
public class MyService : Service {
    public object Any(MyRequest request) {
        base.Request.Items["RequestDto"] = request;
        return MyResponse { ... };
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@{
   var myRequest = (MyRequest)base.Request.Items["RequestDto"];
}
```

#### Wrapping Re-usable functionality in Request Filters

If you find you need to access the Request DTO in your views a lot, then rather than manually assigning it in each service, you can create a Request [Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) or if you want it assigned all the time in a [Global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters).

```
public class SetRequestDtoAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {
    public override void Execute(
        IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        req.Items["RequestDto"] = requestDto;
    }
}
```

Then you can add this behavior by decorating the `[SetRequestDto]` attribute on different levels of granularity on either an Action, Service, Request DTO or base class.